# What is the function of は in the context?

Tags: grammar

Previously, I learnt basic expressions like “アダムさんは先生です。”,”アダムさんは医者ですが。” I thought は functions like “am/is/are” in English. But when I start learning Japanese verb this morning, I got a bit confused. 
“ひろしさんはテレビを見ません。” what is は’s function in this sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

は absolutely, definitely does **not** mean 'am/is/are'. That role is played by です in your example sentences.

は marks the **topic** of the sentence i.e,

> Thing I want to talk about **は** what I want to say about it.

There is no equivalent concept in English so it causes a lot of confusion for many Japanese learners. It is commonly translated (very clumsily) as 'as for' e.g.

> アダムさんは先生です
>   As for Adam, (he) is a teacher. = Adam is a teacher.
>   アダムさんは医者ですが
>   As for Adam, (he) is a doctor, but ... = Adam is a doctor, but ...
>   ひろしさんはテレビを見ません
>   As for Hiroshi, (he) doesn't watch television. = Hiroshi doesn't watch television.

In all these examples I'm marking the thing I want to talk about (i.e the person) with は and then saying something about them.

The topic doesn't have to be just a single noun. It can be a long and complex phrase e.g. "As for that man stood on one leg on the edge of the mountain over there **は** he's going to fall off."

If you're learning from a resource that just teaches you phrases without teaching you the grammar properly, you're going to enter a world of pain.

Finally, here's a [link](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/22/whats-the-difference-between-wa-%E3%81%AF-and-ga-%E3%81%8C) that we normally send people to look at on は/が related questions. It may be a bit confusing at this stage, but it might help.

Footnote:

I wonder if アダムさんは医者です**が** was a typo for アダムさんは医者です**か**. The latter would obviously be "As for Adam, is (he) a doctor?" = "Is Adam a doctor?".